# IBM MQ How read one by one message, not all available in a queue manager at once?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-mq, mq

Now, my app receives all available messages in a Queue manager. I collect them locally and process one by one. 
Could do I configure it to receive one message, do some work (it can take some time), delete the received message, repeat? Is this behavior possible with IBM MQ?
The code was updated

```
function listenToMQ() {
      const qMgr = inbound.queueManagerName;
      const qName = inbound.queueName;
      const connName = inbound.host;

      const cno = new mq.MQCNO();
      const sco = new mq.MQSCO();
      const csp = new mq.MQCSP();
      const cd = new mq.MQCD();
      cno.SecurityParms = csp;
      csp.UserId = inbound.userID;
      csp.authenticationType = 0;
      cno.Options |= MQC.MQCNO_CLIENT_BINDING;
      cd.ConnectionName = connName;
      cd.ChannelName = inbound.channelName;
      cd.SSLClientAuth = MQC.MQSCA_OPTIONAL;
      cd.MaxMsgLength = 104857600;
      cno.ClientConn = cd;
      cno.SSLConfig = sco;

      mq.setTuningParameters({
        syncMQICompat: true   });

      mq.Connx(qMgr, cno, function(err, hConn) {
        if (err) {
          logger.errorLogger().error(err.message);
        } else {
          const od = new mq.MQOD();
          od.ObjectName = qName;
          od.ObjectType = MQC.MQOT_Q;
          const openOptions = MQC.MQOO_BROWSE;
          mq.Open(hConn, od, openOptions, function(err, hObj) {
            queueHandle = hObj;
            if (err) {
              logger.errorLogger().error(err.message);
            } else {
              getMessages();
            }
          });
        }   }); }


    function getMessages() {
      const md = new mq.MQMD();
      const gmo = new mq.MQGMO();

      gmo.Options =
        MQC.MQGMO_NO_SYNCPOINT |
        MQC.MQGMO_MQWI_UNLIMITED |
        MQC.MQGMO_CONVERT |
        MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
      gmo.Options |= MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST;

      gmo.MatchOptions = MQC.MQMO_NONE;

      mq.setTuningParameters({
        getLoopPollTimeMs: 500   });   mq.Get(queueHandle, md, gmo, getCB); }



      function getCB(err, hObj, gmo, md, buf, hConn) {
        if (md.Format == "MQSTR") {
          console.log(md);
          const message = decoder.write(buf);
          updateDB(getMetaFeed(message));
        } 
        mq.Cmit(hConn);
      }

            gmo.Options &= ~MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST;
            gmo.Options |= MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_NEXT;   }
```

Comment: Currently are a only browsing each message, calling `applyFeed(message);`, and then repeating until you get to the last message. No message will be removed from the queue with a browse. What does the function applyFeed do? If you remove the BROWSE GMOs then it will remove each message from the queue. If you want to wait until you finish processing the message then change `MQC.MQGMO_NO_SYNCPOINT` to `MQC.MQGMO_SYNCPOINT` and then call `MQCMIT` when are finished processing the message.

Comment: Could you show an example of how to use MQCMIT in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, most certainly you can.

Your application can get one message, perhaps using syncpoint if it is a message that drives some work that needs done, do the work and then when the work is done commit the get of the message and then go and get the next one. If the work that needs to be done is also transactional (e.g. update a database), then a global transaction could be used to commit both the MQ message and the update of the other transactional resource at the same time.

The code you show in your question appears to be doing a browse of messages (queue opened with `MQOO_BROWSE` and then messages read using `MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST` and then `MQGMO_BROWSE_NEXT`).  I'm not sure how or when your application currently removes the messages from the queue?

Your current code appears to be processing the messages one by one already, so the only changes needed would be to the get options (and to add a commit call).

Comment: Yes, for now, the app only browse messages and doesn't remove. I need to save a message in DB and after that remove the message and process next

Comment: Could you look at this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59394746/ibm-mq-how-process-message-one-by-one-from-queue

Comment: Update.
When we start our app, the Queue might contain for example 10 messages. It is important for us to read the first message, execute database update (it might take from 2 till 4 minutes), then delete the message from the queue (execute commit) and only after we have processed the first message, we can start processing the second one.

The current issue is that we read messages one by one almost immediately and we do not wait until DB update is finished.

Comment: Where in your code are you executing the database update? Is this not run inline in your program? Is that why it doesn't wait. Your program is asking for the next message, MQ is not pushing it to you, so why does your program not wait to ask for the next message until after it has finished the DB update?

Comment: I update the code. The database update is called in function getCB.

Comment: I see that your code calls mq.Cmit, but you are not using Syncpoint, so I'm not sure what this is trying to achieve. I don't understand why your code doesn't process one message and update the DB before moving on to the next message - could you elaborate further on the problem you see that leads you to believe that this is the case please?